# Why do I have to give it a name?

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates

I'm trying to do some game programming in Unity and due to this fact I had to choose either C# or Javascript or (Boo). I chose C# because at least has decent IDE and in fact it is bit faster than Javascript and object oriented. Anyway, I'm declaring delegate:

```
private delegate Object Instantiate_(Object ,Vector3 ,Quaternion );
```

and I'm getting compiler error telling me that I'm supposed to name those params. Any logical reason why? I'm not using them anywhere, nor I refer to them, so what's the point in naming them?

Comment: if you are not using them, why even have them in the first place? why not just have `private delegate Object Instantiate_()`?

Comment: because this is the syntax for defining a delegate

Comment: I don't know if you are new to C# or if you have a special case for using delegates but when I see one I usually think that what the writer really meant was to use an `event`.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter names are required so that you could use invocation syntax that specifies parameter names explicitly:

```
public delegate object MakePersonDelegate(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth);

MakePersonDelegate myDelegate = ...;
myDelegate(lastName: "Smith", firstName: "John", dateOfBirth: new DateTime(1985, 1, 1));
```

Note how this code switched first and last name around; the delegate *will* get them in the correct order, though: `"John"` will be passed to the first formal parameter of the delegate, and `"Smith"` will be passed to the second parameter.

Comment: seems bit silly, if anything I should get warning not error. Why error? Silly rule. Why would I want to swap parameters during invocation? To make my code more confusing to the next dev? Guys I don't mean to sound negative (I have C++ background) but those few weeks I'm familiarizing myself with C# and comparing to C++ I see that all this talk about C# being more readable, maintainable are just a old wifes tales.

Comment: @smallB maybe learn the basics of C# before dispensing blanket condemnations?

Comment: @smallB Since C# supports this syntax it needs to be either an error at the declaration or at the invocation with named arguments. You may want to *name* parameters during invocation because several of them may have the same type. How do you know which of the two strings is the first name and which one is last? How about functions with five params of the same type? It gets confusing really fast, and the language provides you means to mitigate it; an ability to swap comes as an added bonus - you do not *have to* do it, but it's nice to know that you can.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "How do you know which of the two strings is the first name and which one is last?" - I'm passing them in the right (declared) order.

Comment: @dbaseman I've learned basics of C#. Believe me few weeks is enough to do it. Especially for someone with C++ background. In C# most of the things are simplified versions of C++ stuff. I've also during my studies did Java and what's the difference between Java and C#? Very little, one have to say.

Comment: @smallB Although two weeks is certainly enough to get the basics right, it's certainly too short a time to gain an appreciable understanding of the language. Although there was little difference between Java and C# in the beginning, they diverged by C#2.0 enough for the differences to become noticeable, and with C#3.5's support for functional programming style the two languages became rather different. As far as the "simplified C++" goes, there are things in C# that you simply cannot achieve in C++ (read about reflection to learn what I mean).

Comment: @smallB "I'm passing them in the right (declared) order." I think you are missing the point: if the delegate signature is declared as `void MyDelegate(string,string)` the declared order tells you only that you have a string followed by a string. The person programming to a signature like that really has no idea of the *meaning* of these two strings, unless you give them names. By the way, if you are using visual studio, have you been enjoying [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense)? Parts of it are made possible by the requirement to name your parameters.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I believe that C# is just different type of Java.